# Working with multiple github account on same machine

Tags: git, github

I have 2 accounts , one is for personal use and another one is for professional usage. Now to work with multiple github  accounts I have to perform [these steps](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/manage-multiple-github-accounts-the-ssh-way-2dadc30ccaca/) ,

1. Generating the SSH keys
2. Adding the new SSH key to the corresponding GitHub account
3. Registering the new SSH Keys with the ssh-agent
4. Creating the SSH config File
5. One active SSH key in the ssh-agent at a time

***Now the account that I am using for professional usage is shared with 5 more people , i.e we are using same credential.***

Now my question is , If I perform those above tasks(1-5), then will they face any error while pushing or fetching repository? If yes then how to bypass the issue?

Thanks and regards

Comment: I don't see a reason that setup would cause problems when working with multiple people.

Comment: "Now the account that I am using for professional usage is shared with 5 more people , i.e we are using same credential." That sounds bad

Comment: It is what it is , what can I do about it..!! XD @matt

Comment: So Your are saying they wont face any problem If I setup at my end? @mousetail

Comment: I'm saying I don't see any reason you will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps *Github* will have an issue with your account if they estimate it is a breach of their terms of service (I warmly invite you to read the terms for your subscription),

but I don't see any technical limitations coming from `git` or `ssh` alone.

---

I must say I don't understand what you mean with :

> 5. One active SSH key in the ssh-agent at a time